# breeze.d.ts casing of "autoGeneratedKeyType" is wrong, i think

Tags: breeze

i am using breeze in conjunction with typescript. i have the following typescript code:

```
    var eto = <breeze.EntityTypeOptions>new Object();
    eto.autogeneratedKeyType = breeze.AutoGeneratedKeyType.Identity;
```

at run time breeze complains of an unknown property called "autogeneratedKeyType". from what i can tell breeze is expecting "autoGeneratedKeyType"... please note the casing difference...

perhaps i am doing something wrong... does anyone have any suggestions? i changed the breeze.d.ts to match the casing expected and that appears to work... but i am a javascript beginner and i suspect there is an issue with my code...

off topic one other issue i noticed is that it appears the breeze nuget packages are not up to date with the current version of breeze...

thank you very much

Comment: Not sure I understand, your statement should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand..., but your statement should be

```
 eto.autoGeneratedKeyType = breeze.AutoGeneratedKeyType.Identity.
```

(note the casing - 'G' should be capitalized) The convention in breeze is that all properties are lower camel case and all classes and 'enum' types are upper camel case.

As for the nuget packages and zips on the Breeze WebSite.  The latest Breeze version is 1.3.4. This represents Breeze.js ( the javascript client) version 1.3.4.  The  Breeze.WebApi dll versions at a different rate then the client side javascript so its .NET version number will be different.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: thank you Jay... sorry for not being clear... what i am saying is that the casing in the breeze.d.ts file for this property is with lower case "g", not upper case "G". i would expect it to be uppercase then, not sure... thanks again

Comment: Got it, it's a bug in our typescript defs, I'll fix it for the next release and thx...